# Which applications are bundled with the Zorin OS 17 Pro distro?

Tags: distributions, application, zorin

Zorin OS 17 Pro was just released.  After going through their website and reading numerous articles about it, I don't see the details of a prominent marketing point documented anywhere, namely *a list of which applications are bundled with the Zorin OS 17 Pro distro.*

For example, here is a page on Zorin's website stating that their Pro version is "bundled with alternatives to over $5,000 of professional software":
https://zorin.com/os/pro/#productivity

But the bundled apps are not specified.

So, which applications *are* bundled with the Zorin OS 17 Pro distro?

Comment: The YouTube Channel ExplainingComputers recently posted a video reviewing Zorin OS 17 (Pro), where he shows all apps [preinstalled](https://youtu.be/_FryhC19wu8?t=1077). First he quickly shows the app menu and then goes into more detail.

Comment: Thank you Tobi.  I watched part of the video, and although I would prefer a text-based list, this is definitely a big help.  Thanks again.  BTW, do you happen to know the specs of the computer on which that demonstration is recorded?  The speed is impressive, and everything seems to run very fluidly.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a complete list, but the help page on [Alternatives to Windows Apps](https://help.zorin.com/docs/apps-games/alternatives-to-windows-apps/) annotates some apps as "pre-installed in Zorin OS Pro". Here's the list filtered to include only those items:

| Type | Windows App | Alternative pre-installed in Zorin OS Pro |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Office | Microsoft OneNote | Xournal++ |
| Office | Microsoft Publisher, Adobe InDesign, Affinity Publisher | Scribus |
| Office | Autodesk AutoCAD, SOLIDWORKS | FreeCAD, LibreCAD |
| Graphics & Reading | Adobe Photoshop, Affinity Photo, Paint.NET, PaintShop Pro, Sketchbook | Krita |
| Graphics & Reading | Adobe Illustrator, Affinity Designer | Inkscape |
| Graphics & Reading | Adobe Lightroom | Darktable |
| Graphics & Reading | Amazon Kindle | Foliate |
| Sound & Video | Adobe Premiere Pro, VEGAS Pro | Kdenlive |
| Sound & Video | Autodesk 3ds Max, Cinema 4D, Adobe After Effects | Blender |
| Sound & Video | Ableton Live, FL Studio, Adobe Audition | Ardour |
| Sound & Video | Streamlabs Desktop, XSplit Broadcaster | OBS Studio |
| System Tools | Microsoft Hyper-V | VirtualBox |

Comment: Thank you.  Although not a complete list, that format is *very* helpful.

Comment: Really though you should be asking Zorin's support for this. You're entitled to know what you're paying for (or will be paying for).

Comment: You know, that's a good point.  I didn't think of it in those terms.